# Accessing different CSS files

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I've got this on my `_layout.cshtml` page:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

This points to a css file that contains all the styles of the application.

I wanted to create another css file with different styles in it and put a combobox, radiobutton, etc, in a view so that the user could choose "style A" or "style B", like user preferences.

Imagine a combobox:

```
<select>
    <option value="default">Default Theme</option>
    <option value="light">Light Theme</option>
    <option value="dark">Dark Theme</option>
    <option value="silver">Silver Theme</option>
</select>
```

[image: ComboBox]

The user would select the theme and the application would point to a different style sheet.

**EDIT**

OK, I've got two style sheets now: `site.css` and `dark.css`. In the `App_Start` folder, I've got the lines:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/dark").Include("~/Content/dark.css"));
```

The resulting style of the app is a mix of the two stylesheets! I don't want that, I want to be able to switch between one and the other.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure is. A little javascript would be easiest, is that alright?

Comment: Of course it is, can you show me how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523932/css-background-color-based-on-select-value

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670135/changing-css-stylesheet-src-onchange-of-select-box

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert of cshtml, but if you can load jQuery, I would try something like this:

```
<select id="styleSelect" onchange=changeStyle()>
    <option value="default">Default Theme</option>
    <option value="light">Light Theme</option>
    <option value="dark">Dark Theme</option>
    <option value="silver">Silver Theme</option>
</select>
```

Then include this script in your `<head>` part

```
<script>
function changeStyle(){
    if($( "#styleSelect" ).val()=="default"){
        $('link[href="oldstylesheet.css"]').attr('href','default.css');
    }
    if($( "#styleSelect" ).val()=="light"){
        $('link[href="oldstylesheet.css"]').attr('href','light.css');
    }
    if($( "#styleSelect" ).val()=="dark"){
        $('link[href="oldstylesheet.css"]').attr('href','dark.css');
    }
    if($( "#styleSelect" ).val()=="silver"){
        $('link[href="oldstylesheet.css"]').attr('href','silver.css');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the lines: `$('link[href="oldstylesheet.css"]').attr('href','default.css');`. The stylesheet is being referenced by the line `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`